# Capture CTRL+A, CTRL+C keys/events in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, air, keyboard, adobe, key

How to capture <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> events in flex? It looks like they are special keys/combinations.

As I understand in Flex 3.4 I can capture <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> by capturing [`Event.SELECT_ALL`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:selectAll), and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> by capturing [`Event.COPY`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:copy). BUT it complains that there are no `SELECT_ALL` static const in Event class.

I'm using Flex SDK 3.4 and Flex Builder for Linux (Ubuntu).

```
public function MyCanvas()
{
    super();

    focusEnabled = true;

    addEventListener(Event.SELECT_ALL, onSelectAll); // It complains here
    addEventListener(Event.COPY, onCopy); // and here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Flex 3.4 language reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/index.html) there is SELECT_ALL in Event class. What version of Flex SDK are you using? Can you post example of your code?

Update: It seems the SELECT_ALL has been added in Flash Player 10. Based on [this](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/10/27/complete-list-of-new-flash-player-10-apis/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this from the API, but it could be an issue of targeting the right Flash player version.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not targeting Flash 10.  In Project > Properties > Flex Compiler, make sure you've set either **Require Flash Version: 10.0.0** (under HTML Wrapper -- yours may read 9.x.x) or otherwise specified the compiler argument **-target-player=10.0.0**.  That ought to do the trick.